# How to register coffeescript transpiler in ES6 way?

Tags: ecmascript-6, coffeescript, rollupjs

Previously I've been using following in my JS entry points:

```
require('coffeescript/register');
module.exports = require('./entry.coffee');
```

What is the corresponding ES6 syntax of this?
Following does not seem to register anyhing.

```
import 'coffeescript/register';
export * from 'entry.coffee';
```

Error is:
`Cannot find module 'entry.coffee'`
Tested on Coffeescript 2.0 beta2.

**Update:**
Changing path to relative:

```
import 'coffeescript/register';
export * from './entry.coffee';
```

finds the `entry.coffee`, but treats it as JS. Hence, Coffeescript is not handled by transpiler.

Comment: Um, no JS runtime implements modules natively by default (the *most* recent versions of *some* have it behind a flag). So how are you transpiling the ES6? That syntax should throw an error if you try to run it directly.

Comment: I'm using RollupJS, and it seems to handle ES6 imports just fine in it's rollup.config.js

Comment: That's a essential piece of information that should have been in your question. You probably need to fix the path in your rollup.config. Coffeescript is likely a red herring here.

Comment: @JaredSmith Not at all. I've changed path to relative. It finds the module, but treats it as JS, not Coffeescript. Hence my original question still remains: how to import Coffeescript module (ES6-style export) from pure JS file (without preprocessing) handled by Node.js?

Comment: Not sure what you have against preprocessing since it reduces page load time, bundle-size, etc. That'd be the way to do it: just compile the coffeescript before passing it to rollup.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `coffeescript/register` if you're transpiling the CoffeeScript as part of your bundling process (which you need to, if you're using Rollup) — that's just a way to enable Node to run CoffeeScript files without having to first convert them.

Instead, try adding [rollup-plugin-coffee-script](https://github.com/lautis/rollup-plugin-coffee-script) to your rollup.config.js file.

Comment: Already using [rollup-plugin-coffee2](https://github.com/zeekay/rollup-plugin-coffee2) for the project code.
Thing is: I'm trying to keep config itself in Coffeescript file: rollup.config.coffee
Hence the need to add Coffeescript in runtime, which worked fine with CommonJS require().

Comment: Maybe you could create a rollup.config.js that looks like this:

`require('coffeescript/register'); module.exports = require('./rollup.config.coffee');`